# React Native - FlatList not rendering images and Text

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm doing a welcome flatlist for the first-time users, I have an image and text to be shown, but it does not render any image, what am I doing wrong? When I put the path in the View it works, but when I put in the imagePath it shows a blank screen

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import ProgressCircle from 'react-native-progress-circle';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {TextInput, Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import styles from './styles';
import {blue} from 'chalk';

<FlatList
  horizontal={true}
  data={onboardingList}
  renderItem={this.Welcome}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>;

const onboardingList = [
  {
    screenText1: 'Get weekly overviews and find',
    screenText2: 'out whats impacting your health',
    screenText3: 'and wellness.',
    imagePath: require('../../assets/images/wellbeing.png'),
    nextScreen: 'HabitTracking',
    progressCirclePercentage: 20,
  },
  {
    screenText1: 'Explore healthyroutines and get',
    screenText2: 'reminders to stay motivated along',
    screenText3: 'the way.',
    imagePath: require('../../assets/images/HabitTracking.png'),
    nextScreen: 'Recommendation',
    progressCirclePercentage: 40,
  },
];
const Welcome = (item, navigation) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Image source={item.imagePath} style={styles.image} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.text_field}>
        <Text style={styles.textContent}>{item.screenText1}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textContent}>{item.screenText2}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textContent}>{item.screenText3}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(item.nextScreen)}>
          <ProgressCircle
            percent={item.progressCirclePercentage}
            radius={30}
            borderWidth={2}
            color="#3399FF"
            shadowColor="white"
            bgColor={'white'}>
            <Icon name="arrowright" size={25} color="black"></Icon>
          </ProgressCircle>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

Bonus question, the progressCircle is not getting the numbers I'm giving on progressCirclePercentage

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, the problem was on my View, I was using item.screenText and it should be only screentext

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View>
      <Image source={imagePath} style={styles.image} />
    </View>

    <View style={styles.text_field}>
      <Text style={styles.textContent}>{screenText1}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textContent}>{screenText2}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textContent}>{screenText3}</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.footer}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleModal(2)}>
        <ProgressCircle
          percent={progressCirclePercentage}
          radius={30}
          borderWidth={2}
          color="#3399FF"
          shadowColor="white"
          bgColor={'white'}>
          <Icon name="arrowright" size={25} color="black"></Icon>
        </ProgressCircle>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
```